# How to Read CSHTML as XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a cshtml file in this file I have a hidden field and static value. I want to read it as a XML file to find the hidden field. As a matter of fact, I don't like open it as text file and search into it.

This is a part of my file and I want to read hidden file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" content="Soha Application" />
    <title>@ViewBag.MeetingTitle</title>    
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/Default/main.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/Default/fa-IR.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <header>
            **<input id="SkinId" type="hidden" value="008BBF4768861284321640F895D68DA1" /> <!-- Please dont change this Code -->**
            <div id="title">
                <h1>@ViewBag.MeetingTitle</h1>
            </div>
            <nav>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Comment: What happens if you save it as a .xml file an try to view it in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

you can read it like a regular xml since its an xhtml

an e.g.
http://sticklebackplastic.com/post/2007/06/28/How-to-use-XmlResolver-Or-reading-an-xhtml-file-in-net.aspx

or use linq with html agility pack

http://web.archive.org/web/20080719181517/http://vijay.screamingpens.com/archive/2008/05/26/linq-amp-lambda-part-3-html-agility-pack-to-linq.aspx

Comment: Actually it's not XML. CSHTML can contain any type of html/xhtml. HTML does is not required to be XML compliant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the XPath extension from here: https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/

This should work for you.  It will return all elements that have an attribute `type="hidden"`

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file); // or XElement.Parse(string);
var hidden = root.XPath("//*[@type='hidden']");
```